# Microcontroller to be used as period counter

Tags: microcontroller, counter

I have a sensor module whoose purpose is to detect speed of moving target. I need to analyse the dat coming out from the sensor . The frequency output from sensor is 5 Khz and then I want to use microcontroller to detect this frequency and hence calculate speed of target. Can anyone suggest how to do it. I am a beginner in this field.

Comment: please re-read your question, it is totally unanswerable. You don't state the type of sensor, the fact that the output is 5 kHz does not help at all. Does 'analyse' mean just calculating the frequency? And what must be done with this frequency? Do you have any experience in programming micro-controllers? In programming at all? What have you don so far, show us your (preliminary) circuit and ditto code.

Comment: Hi the sensor used is doppler effect based sensor. And the frequency stated above is the doppler shifted frequency(coming from the target). Basically I want to calculate speed of target using the sensor module. So I am thinking to use a microcontroller as period counter . I dont have much experience with Programming .

Comment: Which sensor module, don't you have a type, or better: a link to the datasheet? And honestly, if you don't have much experience with programming you will have to acquire that. You won't get a ready-to-run piece of code from us that solves your problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a complete solution is required.

Comment: **Chill out** Wouter & Leon.  The problem statement is simple, and *for the problem actually stated* we **do not** need to know the details of the sensor (though that might cause issues later).  Almost any microcontroller can be configured and programmed to either count cycles on an input signal per some period defined by a large number of cycles of its own clock, or else count cycles of its internal clock per period of an input signal.

Comment: @Smartgirl: This question will probably be closed. Don't be discouraged to ask a new question, but try to include detailed information, ask a specific question and maybe share some thoughts about what ideas you came up with so far.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you can use a microcontroller to calculate? your period. There are several ways to synchronize the detector with the uC, depends on both. You need to know if the output from the detector is analog or digital. If analog, you need a uC with ADC converter. If digital, is it a serial or parallel? You can sample the signal and then do some math with it to calculate the period from the data you acquire.

Comment: Wouter I am not asking for any ready run to piece of code. Only asking for suggestion for designing the circuit and using the microcontroller. The sensor module is doppler effect based . The ouput from sensor goes to preamplifying circuit which amplifies the signal to few volts. It is then sent to uC to further determine the frequency of incoming signal. Hope its clear now. Please stop having preconceived notions about anyone.

Comment: @Smartgirl Ok, so you can have a external ADC converter and then sample digital signal from it onto your uC. You can also get a uC with built in ADC. Do you know what the voltage amplitude represents?

Comment: @Smartgirl Now you say that the uC must measure the frequency, but in the question text you state that the frequency is 5 kHz?